# Why do all of my JQuery drag and drop objects disappear when I try to drop them into each other?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, web

I've been attempting to allow x-amount of dynamically generate div boxes to drag and drop into each other using JQuery.

The problem is that whenever I attempt to drag one into another, every box I have generated, whether involved in the action or not, disappears.

[Here's the fiddler link](http://jsfiddle.net/Bladetrick/J5WAf/4/).

And here is the code:

```
$('#btnOpen').click(function() { OnClientDroppedHandler(); });    


function OnClientDroppedHandler() {

    $('#divWorkSpace').append('<div class="divLoc"><p> I am a box.  Try to Drag and Drop me into another box </p></div>');
    $('.divLoc').resizable();

    $('.divLoc').droppable({
        accept: '.divLoc',
        over: function () {
                $('.divLoc').appendTo($(this));
                $(this).animate({ 'border-width': '5px',
                    'border-color': '#0f0'
                }, 500);
                $('.divLoc').draggable('option', 'containment', $(this));
        }
    });

    $('.divLoc').draggable({
        containment: $('.divWorkSpace')
    });
    return false;      
};
```

The CSS:

```
.divLoc
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color: White;
border: 1px solid black;
z-index: 100;
}
```

The Markup:

```
<input id="btnOpen" type="button" value="Click to Open New Dialog" /> -- Generate at least two dialogs and try to drag and drop them into each other --
<div id="divWorkSpace" style="height: 500px; width: 700px; background-color: Gray;"></div>
```

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your dialogs don't have unique ids. You use class, while you should use id at the following line:

```
$('.divLoc').appendTo($(this));
```

What you do, is that you append ALL your divs to one you drop something on. This means that you append it to itself.

Hope this will help.

Comment: that does make sense.  The problem is that I am generating the boxes dynamically... so my next question would be, how do i obtain the ID of the box I am dragging?

Comment: You don't have to. You can use parameters, provided by jQuery:
http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop

Rewrite you method as 

    over : function( event, ui ){
      $( ui.draggable ).appendTo( $(this) ); 
      ...

    }
ui.draggable should be     jQuery object of dragged dialog.
This should work, but I'm not sure I wrote it correctly, just giving you an idea.


Btw, why are you using 'over', but not drop? http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop